# How to update .getText()?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am making a Login Screen in Java and so far its going good. Now I only have 1 more problem. How to update `.getText()`? If you don't know what I mean keep listening and you'll know.

```
JTextField T1 = new JTextField("USERNAME");
    JTextField T2 = new JTextField("PASSWORD");

String ST1 = T1.getText();
    String ST2 = T1.getText();


if (LOGIN.isEnabled()){
        if (ST1.equals("Jbot")) {

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
                LOGIN.addActionListener(handler);
```

Now if I change the "USERNAME" part in line 1 to Jbot, it lets me login. But if it starts off as USERNAME and **then** you type in Jbot it wont work. I think the problem is that my code is not updating and only does `.getText();` at the beginning.

Comment: `JTextField T2 = new JTextField("PASSWORD");`  Note that since it is a password it should be `JPasswordField T2 = new JPasswordField(..);`.  See [How to Use Password Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

If you want to know the value in a text field then you need to invoke the `getText()` method when an event occurs. In your case your form will probably have a "Login" button. So when the user clicks the "Login" button you get the text and do your test.

So you need to add an `ActionListener` to the "Login" button and invoke the `getText()` method in the `ActionListener`

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information. Or you can read [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

I suggest you look at the table of contents for tutorial on all the Swing basics.

Comment: I dont think you read my whole intire question. If you did Idk what you mean. Please help me still

Comment: I did read your entire question. You need to learn how to do event driven programming, which means your code responds to events initiated by the user. In your case you only do the Login when the user clicks the button. I can't teach you Java, which is why I gave you a link to the tutorial which contains examples you can download and try and modify.

Comment: Okay thanks ill try to find what im looking for in the manual